# C++ STL-like Bidirectional Multimap

Tags: c++, stl

Searching in open-source projects (no-boost), I found a STL-like container `bimap` [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3016/An-STL-like-bidirectional-map) where implements a bidirectional-map. And there is `multimap` in standard C++ libraries.

- But I want to know, Is there any effort to implement a "STL-like
  Bidirectional Multimap" ?
- Or, How can we combine existing containers to make that data
  structure?

*Note: A simple solution is using two `multimap` s in bidirectional way. But it has not good performance. Because, for each `insert`/`remove`/`find` operation we should perform them twice. In addition it allocates more memory.*

*Note II: The `boost.bimap` is a good suggest from HostileFork and KerrekSB, And I will use it if there is no way. But before it I need find a non-boost and small size class library.*

Comment: 'boost::bimap' is header only template code, ergo in terms of size, you only pay for what you use. As HostileFork points out it is also very close to the Standard Libraries methodology.I doubt you will find a smaller size class library.....

Comment: Non boost because?  If I created a project that was a copy paste of all of boost would that satisfy?  How about if in just copy pasted the header files defining your class?

Comment: The problem is I have some limitations and I prefer add the library that satisfy my problem. As you know boost has many other features that I really don't need them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Boost.bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/controlling_collection_types.html) lets you customize the type of collection for both values; both can be non-unique.

Answer (score 2):

Why use random "CodeProject" code when there's a bimap in boost?

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html

Boost code tries to be close to the acceptable methodology of the standard library, and there's a vetting process through which eventually things get accepted.  Maybe in the next standard, who knows?